# logger() slf4j error: The method logger() from the type CoreLogger refers to the missing type Logger

Tags: java, slf4j

I am using `slf4j` imports and i have the following code:

```
do {
            if (error) {
                logger().error("Known issue: clicking [" + item + "] had no effect. Retrying...");
            }
            logger().info("Clicking the [" + item + "] menu item...");
            element.click();
            er`
```

However Eclipse is throwing me the following compilation error: `The method logger() from the type CoreLogger refers to the missing type Logger`. I have all the imports done right, and the same code runs just fine for the person next to me. Do you have any insights into this?

Comment: Please post the code of `CoreLogger` .

Comment: `public interface CoreLogger {

    default Logger logger() {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method logger() from the type CoreLogger refers to the missing
>   type Logger.

It is not a missing import of the class but a class not retrieved at compile time.
Are you sure that the slf4j jar is in the classpath of your project ? 
If it is the case, it is probably a IDE issue : you can identify it by compiling your project outside the IDE (so in command line).
If it doesn't work : you have not the dependency at compile time.
If it works : you should look for a solution in your IDE (clean and refresh the project configuration for example)